# regex patterns on R: n-dash, m-dash, parentheses

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse

I have two regex questions:

**Part 1:**
I have a character vector with strings like this:

```
raw_strings <- c("hello world (abc)", "no hi world (abc(d))")
```

And I want to extract the content inside the first set of parenthesis, like this:

```
clean_strings <- c("abc", "abc(d)")
```

So far, I have been using this:

```
str_extract(raw_strings, "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\))")
```

However, that results in this:

```
"abc" "abc(d"
```

How could I change the expression to keep the final parenthesis?

**Part 2:**
I have some strings that looks like this:

```
b_strings <- c("5.2 ko – word (longer word)", "5.9 ko - two words (long)")
```

I would like to have this:

```
b_strings_clean <- c("word", "two words")
```

So far I have done this:

```
str_extract(ac_meta, "\\s[^-–]*$")
```

Which results in:

```
"word (longer word)" "two words (long)"
```

How can I remove everything after the parenthesis (including the parenthesis)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work using look arounds:

```
str_extract(raw_strings, '(?<=\\().*(?=\\))')
[1] "abc"    "abc(d)"

str_extract(b_strings, '(?<=[–-]\\s).*(?=\\s\\()')
[1] "word"      "two words"
```